# Complex Laurent Series and Contour Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, laurent-series

> Let $f(z) = \sin{(\frac{1}{z})}$, where $z \neq 0$. Find a Laurent Series expansion of $f$ around the annulus $D: 1< |z|<3$.
>
> Use the result to find $$\oint \limits_C z^4\sin{(\frac{1}{z})} dz $$ where $C$ is the curve described by $|z|=2$.

**My attempt:**

Since $z=0$ is the only singular point, but it is not contained in the annulus $D$, we have that $f$ is analytic inside the annulus. Hence, our Laurent Series will be precisely the Maclaurine Series of $f$ in $D$, that is, $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\big( \frac{1}{z}\big)^{2n+1} ~~~ \text{where } z \in D$$

Now, for the second part of our question.

\begin{align}\oint \limits_C z^4\sin{(\frac{1}{z})} dz &= \oint \limits_C z^4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\big( \frac{1}{z}\big)^{2n+1} dz  \end{align}

This is the part where I am stuck and I an unsure how to continue. My trail of thought is the following, but I honestly do not know if this is correct:

Since, clearly $z^4$ is analytic everywhere and we know that our series is analytic inside our annulus $D$, the product of the two (our integrand), will be analytic everywhere in the intersection of their two domains of analyticity (I think I might just have made that word up, but you know what I mean :P ). Hence we have that our integrand is analytic in $D$.

Then, since $C$ is a closed, piecewise smooth curve inside $D$ and our integrand is analytic on $C$, we know, from Cauchy-Goursat, that $$\oint \limits_C z^4\sin{(\frac{1}{z})} dz =0$$

Comment: Cauchy-Goursat assumes simply connected. You do not have that here. What happens when you integrate $\frac{1}{z}$ on a closed contour encircling the origin? What if you have any other power?

Comment: @CameronWilliams . Good point. Is there a way that I can make use of the Residue instead then, perhaps?

Comment: Yes residues are the way to go and this is exactly as I was suggesting in the original comment. Residues come from powers of $z^{-1}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams . If our integrand is called $g$, then $\text{Res}[g, 0] = z^{4} |_{z=0} = 0$ , thus we know that $\oint_{C} g(z) = 2\pi i (0) =0$. Is this correct? :)

Comment: No. You have negative powers coming from $\sin(z^{-1})$. Write out the full Laurent series for $z^4\sin(z^{-1})$ term by term and you'll see what falls out.

Comment: @CameronWilliams . Am I correct in determining that $\text{Res}[g,0] = -\frac{1}{120}$? :). So then we will have that the integral is $2 \pi i \text{Res}[g,0] = -\frac{\pi}{60}i$? :)

Comment: You're almost right. Your signs alternate $+,-,+,-,...$. It's the third term which contributes to the integral, so it should be positive, not negative.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. Thank you! :). I found my mistake. In my taylor series I had $(-1)^{n+1}$, instead of $(-1)^n$, which resulted in my signs being in different order :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams. Thank you so much for your help :).

Comment: Can one have a laurent expansion of a function $f(z)$ around a closed disk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The only non zero coefficient in the Laurent series is $z^{-1}$ or $n=2$. So 
$$
\oint \limits_C z^4\sin{(\frac{1}{z})} dz = \oint \limits_C \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!} \frac{1}{z^{2n-3}} dz=\frac{1}{5!}\oint \frac{1}{z^{}} dz=\frac{1}{5!}\int_0^{2\pi} i d\theta=\frac{\pi i}{60}
$$

Comment: @mathlover - why do we disregard the minus of $-\frac{1}{5!}$?

Comment: Thank you :). That makes perfect sense :)